# How to escape special characters to use for JSON data

Tags: php, javascript, json

```
  `{\
     "wins\":[\"http://nintendos.t15.org/folder.dsos\",\"http://nintendos.t15.org
     /NintendOS%20Office/word.dsos?create=true\"
  ]}`
```

this is my JSON string that is written to the file with PHP.

I don't care which language (JS or PHP), but how would I escape the data (like "\ to ") to use it? The exact code is below:

```
function SaveSession(){
 try{
   if(user){
    var date=new Date();
    var month=date.getMonth()+1;
    var day=date.getDate();
    var year=date.getFullYear();
    var hour=date.getHours();
    var minutes=date.getMinutes();
    var seconds=date.getSeconds();
    if(minutes<10){
        minutes="0"+minutes;
    }
    if(seconds<10){
           seconds="0"+seconds;
    }
    dt=""+month+"/"+day+"/"+year+" "+hour+":"+minutes+":"+seconds+"";
    var session=new Object();
    session.wins=new Array();
    var pages=document.getElementsByClassName("page");
        if(pages[0]){
           session.wins.push(pages[0].getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].src);
        }
        if(pages[1]){                            
                   session.wins.push(pages[1].getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].src);
        }
        if(pages[2]){
                   session.wins.push(pages[2].getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].src);
        }if(pages[3]){
                   session.wins.push(pages[3].getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].src);
        }if(pages[4]){
           wins.push(pages[4].getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].src);
        }if(pages[5]){
                   session.wins.push(pages[5].getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].src);
        }if(pages[6]){
               session.wins.push(pages[6].getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].src);
        }if(pages[7]){
               session.wins.push(pages[7].getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].src);
        }if(pages[8]){
               session.wins.push(pages[8].getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].src);
        }if(pages[9]){
               session.wins.push(pages[9].getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].src);
        }
            ajaxObj.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(ajaxObj.readyState>=4 && ajaxObj.status==200){
    }
    else{
    }
     }
     var sessionData=escape(JSON.stringify(session));
     ajaxObj.open("POST","req.php",true);
     ajaxObj.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     ajaxObj.send("save_session=true&user="+username+"&session="+sessionData+"");
}
}
catch(err){
    alert("Error. Unable to save session. "+err+"");
}
 }
```

Basically, I want to save the JSON object to a file, and I need to escape the special characters if I ever want to use it again.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: totally confused as to what you want to do... (un)escape it correctly to re-parse the JSON string, or before writing, or to load it as PHP object, or...? Looks like what you should fix is the bit that writes this out to the file.

Comment: 1. Parse data to JSON string
2. Escape special character(s) \" and/or \'
3. Write the new string to file (PHP)

Comment: I've tried escape(), and a replace().

Answer (score 1):

haven't tested it, but it might work :)

```
<?php 

str_replace('\"', '"', $jsonString);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but now when I try to request the data using AJAX, it still comes up with \", which makes it unable to parse.

How can I escape it in JS?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple actually.

```
<?php
    $a = array('x' => '"xyzhttp://test\escape');
    $b = json_encode($a); // {"x":"\"xyzhttp:\/\/test\\escape"}
    print_r(json_decode($b, true)); // Array ( [x] => "xyzhttp://test\escape ) 
?>
```

Just use the `json_*` functions.

Comment: My stupid hosting providers' server does not have the latest on PHP.